# Updating State for Wear OS Tile (Samsung Watch Pro 5)

Tags: wear-os-tiles

I have program that is trying to show on the watch the time of the next prayer. The main feature that I am trying to develope is for the Tile WearOS. The Solution that has been offered by the [android.developer](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/tiles/update#choose_an_update_workflow) is either using Worker or `setFreshnessIntervalMillis()`

Could you please give me a solution for this. I f I have to use Worker, how could I code for this?

I tried to use the `setFreshnessIntervalMillis()` it did refresh the tile very some milliseconds (minimum 20 seconds) but, It did not work in Samsung Watch 5 pro. It may take a long time (unpredictable) when it could be shown at later time.

The output of mawaqit.getNextPrayer() would be `{nextPrayerDate=Saturday, March 16, 2024 18:35, nextPrayerTime=18:35, nextPrayerName=Maghrib, shuruqTime=06:27, countdownTime=00:21:18}`

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalHorologistApi::class)
class MainTileService : SuspendingTileService() {

    override suspend fun resourcesRequest(
        requestParams: RequestBuilders.ResourcesRequest
    ): ResourceBuilders.Resources {
        return ResourceBuilders.Resources.Builder().setVersion(RESOURCES_VERSION).build()
    }

    override suspend fun tileRequest(
        requestParams: RequestBuilders.TileRequest
    ): TileBuilders.Tile {
        val nextPrayerData = getNextPrayerAndCountdown(this)

        val singleTileTimeline =
            TimelineBuilders.Timeline.Builder()
                .addTimelineEntry(
                TimelineBuilders.TimelineEntry.Builder()
                    .setLayout(
                        LayoutElementBuilders.Layout.Builder().setRoot(tileLayout(this, nextPrayerData)).build())
                    .build()
            ).build()

        return TileBuilders.Tile.Builder()
            .setFreshnessIntervalMillis(60 * 1000) // (n * 1000) seconds
            .setResourcesVersion(RESOURCES_VERSION)
            .setTileTimeline(singleTileTimeline)
            .build()
    }
}

private suspend fun getNextPrayerAndCountdown(context: Context): Map<String, String> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val mawaqit = Mawaqit(context.getString(R.string.masjid_id))
        mawaqit.getNextPrayer()
    }
}

private fun tileLayout(context: Context, nextPrayerData: Map<String, String?>) :
        LayoutElementBuilders.LayoutElement {

    println("RefreshData: $nextPrayerData")

    val nextPrayerName = nextPrayerData["nextPrayerName"] ?: "Unknown"

    val nextPrayerTime = nextPrayerData["nextPrayerTime"] ?: "Unknown"

    val columnBuilder = LayoutElementBuilders.Column.Builder()
        .addContent(
            Text.Builder(context, "$nextPrayerName $nextPrayerTime")
                .setColor(argb(Colors.DEFAULT.onSurface))
                .setTypography(Typography.TYPOGRAPHY_TITLE2)
                .build()
        )

    return PrimaryLayout.Builder(buildDeviceParameters(context.resources))
        .setContent(columnBuilder.build())
        .build()
}
```

```kotlin
class NextPrayerWorker(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val mawaqit = Mawaqit("dawah-kassel")
        val nextPrayerData = mawaqit.getNextPrayer()
        return Result.success(
            workDataOf(
                WORK_NAME to nextPrayerData.toString()
            )
        )
    }

    companion object {
        const val WORK_NAME = "NextPrayerWorker"
    }

}

/*
    This is an implementation of the getNextPrayerAndCountdown function
    using WorkManager and CoroutineWorker. This function should be called from
    the tileRequest function in MainTileService.
 */
//private suspend fun retrieveNextPrayerData(): Map<String, String> {
//    // Schedule periodic work request
//    val periodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<NextPrayerWorker>(
//        repeatInterval = 1, // Repeat every 1 second
//        repeatIntervalTimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS
//    ).build()
//
//    WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
//        NextPrayerWorker.WORK_NAME,
//        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.UPDATE,
//        periodicWorkRequest
//    )
//
//    val workerResult = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
//        WorkManager.getInstance(this@MainTileService)
//            .getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(periodicWorkRequest.id).value
//    }
//
//    val nextPrayerData = workerResult?.let {
//        if (it.state.isFinished) {
//            val nextPrayerData = it.outputData.getString(NextPrayerWorker.WORK_NAME)
//            return@let stringToMap(nextPrayerData!!)
//        } else {
//            // Handle the case when the worker is not finished
//            // You might want to return a default map or handle it based on your app logic
//            return@let emptyMap<String, String>()
//        }
//    } ?: emptyMap()
//    return nextPrayerData
//}
//
//fun stringToMap(stringMap: String): Map<String, String> {
//    val map = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
//
//    // Remove braces from the string representation
//    val cleanedStringMap = stringMap
//        .replace("{", "")
//        .replace("}", "")
//
//    // Split the string by comma and trim whitespaces
//    val entries = cleanedStringMap.split(",")
//
//    // Iterate over each entry and split by '=' to get key-value pairs
//    entries.forEach { entry ->
//        val (key, value) = entry.split("=").map { it.trim() }
//        map[key] = value
//    }
//
//    return map
//}
```